# После обновление nginx, cайт перестал работать

Tags: nginx, debian, update, config

Появилась необходимость перейти системы с HTTP 1.1 на HTTP 2. Выполнял по инструкции, которая доступна по ссылки [тут](https://blog.programs74.ru/how-to-enable-alpn-on-nginx/). Выбрал вариант "перекомпиляции Nginx из исходников с нужными опциями.".
Выполнил все по инструкции и все хорошо, захожу на сайт. А он не работает, как будь-то сервер не запущен. 
Сделал проверку статуса и получил [Скриншот №1](https://prnt.sc/lln992)

**error.log**

```
2018/11/22 15:32:55 [notice] 20094#20094: signal process started
2018/11/22 15:44:32 [notice] 21071#21071: signal process started
```

**Операционная система:** debian;
**Вопрос:** В чем дело и куда копать?

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

**Дополнение:**
Перезапустил сервер и ошибки (то что в скриншоте нет) - все хорошо. Но сайт не работает( как будь-то сервер не включен)

Comment: Что значит «как будь-то сервер не включен»? Как открываете? Какой конфиг nginx?

Comment: @andreymal, порт 80 не прослушивается. Добавил к вопросу

Comment: @andreymal, нет. я уже много манипуляций сделал ( все что находил в интернете, пробовал). Файл конфига изменился но результат тот же

Comment: Не похоже, что в показанных вами конфигах настроен какой-то сайт

Comment: @andreymal  оно работало до обновления, может быть конфиг перезаписался. У Вас есть мысль куда копать?

Comment: Вернуть старый конфиг?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86130/discussion-between-node-pro-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
 listen my_ip:80;
 server_name mysite.com;
 location / {
  expires-1;
  proxy_ssl_name $server_name;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
 }
 access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite/http_access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite/http_error.log;
}
```

Простейшая конфигурация.

Соответственно:

`listen` - внешняя `ip` вашего сервера

`server_name` - название сайта

`proxy_pass` - куда проксируется запрос (тут например `localhost`), хотя может и на `123.123.123.123`

Если файлы сайта лежат на сервере, то можно без проксирования обойтись, что-то типа:

```
location / {
 root /path/to/dir/site;
}
```

С одной стороны у всех конфиги примерно одинаковые, но различия есть и без их понимания ошибку не исправить.

Иерархия блоков такая:

```
http {
 ...
 server {
  ...
  location / {
   ...
  }
  ...
 }
 ...
}
```